# How can I communicate between android client and c# server on iis?

Tags: c#, android, server, iis-8, wwwroot

I have an android application and I got windows server (2012) from my college.
I wrote the code of the server on my private computer and worked localhost, now I want to publish (hope that I'm using the right words) my code to the server that I got from my college so that my android app would send the request to that server and get the data from it.

I would like to uderstand what are the steps that I sohuld do in order to "install" my server app code on the server (and where? is it in wwwroot?) so that my android client could send requests to it and get data from it.

tnx!

Comment: in c# make web api, and connect android client. you will find both info and tutorial online for installing iis and making web api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install IIS on your server machine. you can install it from Control Panel -> Programs & Features -> Add/Remove Windows Features ( you can google it for step by step guide).

Once it is installed. You can publish your SERVER APP CODE on the IIS.

1- You can publish by copy the code in any folder on the server

2- Goto IIS : Control Panel > Administrative Tools > IIS (assuming that you have already installed IIS)

3- Add new Website and select the APP CODE FOLDER

after a successful publish, you can browse the url by http://[YOUR-SERVER-NAME]:PORT/

so by using the url in your android client you can communicate between your apps.

**Note: both the server and the android application must be on same network**

If you face any difficulty in achieving any steps you can search on youtube with the terminology, you can easily find the video tutorial.